# REST API Error: Refused to connect to ... because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive:

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, google-chrome-extension

I am trying to update my status on twitter using the REST API to "Update Status".

I am posting it on Twitter's own site, this is what I'm posting:

```
$.post("https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/update.json?status=Hello")
```

However I get the error

> Refused to connect to
>   'https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/update.json?status=Hello'
>   because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive:
>   "connect-src graph.facebook.com pay.twitter.com
>   analytics.twitter.com upload.twitter.com 'self'".

Can anyone help? I'm just finding the twitter tutorial a bit confusing; all I want to accomplish is using an api that can easily send tweets. Do I need to do this in a chrome extension?

Comment: Are you using cordova/ionic?

Answer (score 2):

You need to add `api.twitter.com` to your CSP:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy"
    content="connect-src graph.facebook.com
             pay.twitter.com analytics.twitter.com
             upload.twitter.com api.twitter.com 'self'">
```

Not sure exactly what your current content security policy looks like, but the correct domain (`api.twitter.com`) needs to be added to it. This would be in your `index.html`, by the way.

If you want to see the docs, I'd check out the ones from [MDN "Using Content Security Policy"](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/CSP/Using_Content_Security_Policy).

## Edit

You can change the CSP in the `manifest.json` ([read the docs](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/contentSecurityPolicy)):

```
{
  ...,
  "content_security_policy": "[POLICY STRING GOES HERE]"
  ...
}
```

Comment: I just want to use this in a chrome extension. Basically I just want to create a tweet, nothing more.

Comment: what do I put in my policy string then?

Comment: @ZimbabweElephant, what I put in my answer. The stuff that goes in the "content" part of the meta tag usually. Research chrome extension docs for information about how to format the policy strings.